# How to pull image from first post and display it on monthly Archive page?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, archives, post-thumbnails

I am using a custom template for my monthly Archive page. This page will show all the posts-links (category-wise) for the particular month.

In the very first post of each month, there shall be only one image.
I want to pull this image and need to show it as a thumbnail on the specific-month archive page, before the posts-links of the said month.

How can it be possible? Many thanks for kind help.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first image listed in the "gallery" section of your post (not the visible gallery if there is one, but the one if you click on insert image)

http://snipplr.com/view/12513/display-the-first-image-attachment-of-a-wordpress-post/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Get The Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) plugin and call it in archive template for first post (on [`is_month()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_month) conditional if needed).